# #define f(x1,x2) x1##x2 void main() { int i; int s1,s10,s100,s1000; for(i=1;i<5;i*=10) printf("%d ",(f(s,i)=i)); }

Tags: c, tokenize

Here is  a piece of code. But i know this will clearly give an error "si undeclared" . Is there any solution for i is to be replaced with its value while token pasting

```
#define f(x1,x2) x1##x2 
void main() 
{ 
int i,s1,s10,s100,s1000; 

for(i=1;i<=1000;i*=10) 
printf("%d ",(f(s,i)=i));  
}
```

Comment: No, it's simply not possible in C.

Comment: -1, please provide a decent title for your question

Answer (score 0):

try to build your code with `gcc -E`. It will generate the preprocessor code. you will find that the preprocessor code look like that

```
void main() 
{ 
    int i,s1,s10,s100,s1000; 

    for(i=1;i<=1000;i*=10) 
    printf("%d ",(si=i));  
}
```

The preprocessor code is code that the compilator genarate from the origin code before building the binary. in the prprocessor code the compilator replace all macros with its contents. So your compilator will replace `f(s,i)` with the macro content so it will be replaced with `si`

**So doing that in C is impossible**. I suggest to use array instead

instead of `s1` use `s[1]` ...

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mention that there are following steps of the compilation take place:

1. Preprocessing (processing all #define, #include, #ifdef etc)
2. Compilation (actual code compilation and producing the object files)
3. Linking (linking object files to a binary)

`#define` is a pre-processor directive in C, that means if you will do the following:

```
#define MAX 1
```

Then after code preprocessing at all places where there is a `MAX` you will get 1 instead of it.

The following:

```
#define f(x1,x2) x1##x2
```

Makes connects `x1` and `x2` together on preprocessing:

```
f(s, i) => si
```

So at the compilation time you are getting error because the `si` variable was not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

no, but you can use arrays to achieve the same :

```
int i,j;
int arr[4];

for(i=1,j=0;i<=1000;i*=10,j++) 
    printf("%d ",(arr[j]=i));
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason is that macros are a pre-processor thing not a run-time thing. use arrays

```
int i,s[4]; 

for(i=1;i<=4;++i) 
   s[i] = pow(10,i);
}
```